# WPF Applications do not run outside VS Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Hi I have a really strange problem that has occurred where a WPF application that was running fine no longer launches. I have been through everything looking for changes etc to no avail. To try to make sure I was not missing something I created a new WPF project in VS2015 community, targeted at .Net 4 that contained only a Main form with a label on it and it too will not open on Windows 10 or 8.1 (I tried it on 2 different windows 10 machines and an 8.1) but it will open on Windows 7.
 It also runs fine in debug, this is the same situation as the original software.

When you try to run them you get the cursor spinning and then nothing, even worse is there is nothing showing in the event logs to point to a problem and as they run in debug there is nothing there to lead me to an answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it run outside visual studio on the pc where you use visual studio? Did you try to run it elevated?

Comment: You ARE trying to run the <projectName>.exe and NOT <projectName>.vshost.exe, right?

Comment: Doesn't run outside VS on the same PC, and yes running as Administrator doesn't work either.
Copy the file to another Win10 machine and it has the same issue, take it to a Win7 machine and it works no problem.

Comment: Place a try-catch around the contents of App.g.cs Main method in the obj directory and log the error to the event viewer.  You will also need to comment out [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")] from the Main method.

Comment: UPDATE: Just put both applications through Dependency Walker on the Windows 10 machines and they both show API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-2-0.DLL is not found. So I am currently looking into that.

Comment: SOLVED: This is truly awful but it turned out to be Avast Antivirus - hooking any WPF application and not letting it start, even if it was installed and not just an exe in a folder - but there was no indication or the usual alert from Avast to say it was scanning it it just suspended the execution forever. This is only happening on Win 10 and 8 and even though Avast is installed on the Win 7 machines it does not cause this error.